# ValueError: Cannot serialize function: lambda while using makemigrations

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

When I do `python manage.py makemigrations`, i get above error and I am unsure where the error is happening. I saw some post regarding this issue but i find mainly in `DateTimeField()` where the function was passed but in my case I have used `auto_now` attribute instead of some datetime related function.

However, I have used lambda function in the class method as follow.

```
@classmethod
    def get_content_models(cls):
        """
        Return all Package subclasses.
        """
        is_content_model = lambda m: m is not Package and issubclass(m, Package)


def set_helpers(self, context):
    current_package_id = getattr(current_package, "id", None)
    current_parent_id = getattr(current_package, "parent_id", None)
    self.is_current_child = self.parent_id == current_package_id
    self.is_child = self.is_current_child

    def is_c_or_a(package_id):
        parent_id = context.get("_parent_package_ids", {}).get(package_id)
        return self.id == package_id or (parent_id and is_c_or_a(parent_id))
    self.is_current_or_ascendant = lambda: bool(is_c_or_a(current_package_id))
```

I am not clear on this issue, So i have posted for understanding the cause. Is above code creating that issue? If it is the cause, what should be done instead?

I don't know where exactly this issue lies in the models so here is the detail of `models.py of package app` in gist because the code is a bit huge . It is not reached to booking models so I am only putting the code of package app and here it is

https://gist.github.com/SanskarSans/51d2f287309a97163e680cc38abd3e06

UPDATE

In my Package models, I have used the custom field and in that field there was the use of lambda instead of callable function and that was creating an issue. Due to the long file of models, I did not paste it here, I apologize for that.

Here what I had done

```
in_menus = MenusField(_("Show in menus"), blank=True, null=True)

class MenusField(MultiChoiceField):
    """
    ``MultiChoiceField`` for specifying which menus a package should
    appear in.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        choices = [t[:2] for t in getattr(settings, "PAGE_MENU_TEMPLATES", [])]
        default = getattr(settings, "PAGE_MENU_TEMPLATES_DEFAULT", None)
        if default is None:
            default = [t[0] for t in choices]
        elif not default:
            default = None
        if isinstance(default, (tuple, list)):
            d = tuple(default)
            # this lambda should be avoided
            # default = lambda:d 
            default = default_value(d)
        defaults = {"max_length": 100, "choices": choices, "default": default}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        super(MenusField, self).__init__(*args, **defaults)
```

Answer (score 2):

An example replacing the `lambda` with a function.

Borken version:

```
class SomeModel(ParentModel):
    thing_to_export = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), 
                                 default=lambda: ['Default thing'])
```

Working version:

```
def default_thing():
    return ['THIS IS A DEFAULT']

class SomeModel(ParentModel):
    thing_to_export = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50), 
                                 default=default_thing)
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, but something is worth pointing out: you'll need to keep this function around forever, or at least as long as it is referenced in _any_ migration files, because the migration file will want to import it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the pickle module for serialization.

You cannot pickle the class in which `set_helpers` is defined.  That method sets `self.is_current_or_ascendant` to a lambda function, and those are on the list of things that cannot be pickled (see 12.1.4 in https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

The class method cannot be a problem since it only defines one local variable, `is_content_model`, which immediately goes out of scope and gets deleted.  In fact that method, as you presented it here, does nothing at all.

Comment: so how do i solve the issue of ValueError: Cannot serialize function: lambda while using makemigrations?

Comment: Here is my model and I am using mezzanine https://gist.github.com/SanskarSans/51d2f287309a97163e680cc38abd3e06

Answer (score 0):

The follows might be helpful to others in the future.

It worked to change the `lambda` expression into a `function`.

The following `square_root` and `square_root_lambda` worked the same:

```
def square_root(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)

square_root_lambda = lambda x: math.sqrt(x)


print(square_root(4))
print(square_root_lambda(4))
```